# PySpark RDD: mapping strings to integers, removing invalid data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapping, rdd

I've got this RDD in PySpark called `animalRDD` and the header has been removed. The header titles are: `animal, animalBreed, nickName, numberLegs`.

The animalRDD is as follows:

```
[('Dog', 'Poodle', 'Rex', '4'), ('Cat', 'Tabby', 'Digger', 'XXX'), ('Horse', 'Stallion', 'Ozzie', ' '), ('Chicken', 'Rooster', 'Diesel', '2'), ('Bear', 'Black Bear', 'Bazza', '4')]
```

Right now every element in the RDD is a string. I want to map the RDD such that the number of legs becomes an integer.

I know that I can use the following to transform into an integer:

```
animalRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], int(x[3])))
```

However, there is a string 'XXX' and ' ' (blank) in the data. Is there a way to remove these two invalid points so that the RDD returned is this?

```
[('Dog', 'Poodle', 'Rex', 4),('Chicken', 'Rooster', 'Diesel', 2), ('Bear', 'Black Bear', 'Bazza', 4)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this: `animalRDD.filter(lambda x: x[3].strip().isdigit()).map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the 'XXX' and '' removed in the output, something like this could work:

```
tup = [('Dog', 'Poodle', 'Rex', '4'), ('Cat', 'Tabby', 'Digger', 'XXX'), ('Horse', 'Stallion', 'Ozzie', ' '), ('Chicken', 'Rooster', 'Diesel', '2'), ('Bear', 'Black Bear', 'Bazza', '4')]

lst = [list(i) for i in tup]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    try:
        lst[i][3]=int(lst[i][3])
    except ValueError:
        lst[i] = lst[i]
```

If you do want them removed completely from the list:

```
tup = [('Dog', 'Poodle', 'Rex', '4'), ('Cat', 'Tabby', 'Digger', 'XXX'), ('Horse', 'Stallion', 'Ozzie', ' '), ('Chicken', 'Rooster', 'Diesel', '2'), ('Bear', 'Black Bear', 'Bazza', '4')]



lst = [list(i) for i in tup]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    try:
        lst[i][3]=int(lst[i][3])
    except ValueError:
        del lst[i][3]
```

and then to convert back to tuple:

```
tup = [tuple(i) for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to filter and map.

```
rdd.filter(lambda x: x[3].isdigit()).map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], int(x[3]))).collect()

[('Dog', 'Poodle', 'Rex', 4),
 ('Chicken', 'Rooster', 'Diesel', 2),
 ('Bear', 'Black Bear', 'Bazza', 4)]
```